# QQuickWidget with transparent background

Tags: qt, qml

I added in a `QDialog` a`QQuickWidget` to load a `.qml` but its background color is white. My qml declares a `Rectangle` not filling all `QQuickWidget` surface. I need the not filled surface having the same background color of the dialog. What is the way to have a transparent background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the `QQuickWidget` documentation : [`QQuickWidget` Limitations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#limitations)

> Putting other widgets underneath and making the QQuickWidget transparent will not lead to the expected results: the widgets underneath will not be visible. This is because in practice the QQuickWidget is drawn before all other regular, non-OpenGL widgets, and so see-through types of solutions are not feasible. Other type of layouts, like having widgets on top of the QQuickWidget, will function as expected.
>
> When absolutely necessary, **this limitation can be overcome by setting the Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop attribute on the QQuickWidget**. Be aware, however that this breaks stacking order. For example it will not be possible to have other widgets on top of the QQuickWidget, so it should only be used in situations where a semi-transparent QQuickWidget with other widgets visible underneath is required.

Comment: For all people struggling to get the background transparent, only setting the `Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop` attribute will not make the background transparent. You also have to set the `clearColor` of the `QQuickWidget` to transparent.

Answer (score 2):

**Floating cloud:**

```
auto quickWidget = new QQuickWidget();
quickWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::SplashScreen);
quickWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop);
quickWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
quickWidget->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
quickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/cloud.qml"));
quickWidget->show();
```

---

**cloud.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 300
    Canvas {
        id: cloud
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.beginPath();
            var x = 100;
            var y = 170;
            ctx.arc(x, y, 60, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5);
            ctx.arc(x + 70, y - 60, 70, Math.PI * 1, Math.PI * 1.85);
            ctx.arc(x + 152, y - 45, 50, Math.PI * 1.37, Math.PI * 1.91);
            ctx.arc(x + 200, y, 60, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5);
            ctx.moveTo(x + 200, y + 60);
            ctx.lineTo(x, y + 60);
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#797874";
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `QQuickWidget::setClearColor(Qt::transparent)` and set an alpha channel via the `setFormat` call.

Answer (score -1):

project.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets qml quickwidgets
CONFIG += c++17
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget>

/*****************************************************************************/

void show (QUrl component) {
    QDialog* dialog = new QDialog();
    dialog->setStyleSheet("background-color: green;");
    QObject::connect(
        QCoreApplication::instance(),
        SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()),
        dialog,
        SLOT(deleteLater())
    );
    /*QObject::connect(dialog,&QObject::destroyed,[](){
       qDebug() << "destroyed";
    });*/
    QQuickWidget* content = new QQuickWidget(component, dialog);
    content->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    content->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop);
    content->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
    dialog->show();
}

/*****************************************************************************/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    show(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Button.qml"));
    show(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Button.qml"));
    show(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Button.qml"));
    show(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Button.qml"));

    return a.exec();
}

/*****************************************************************************/
```

Button.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Button {
    height: 100
    width: 100
    text: "lol"
}
```

result

[image]

also try gradient background

```
dialog->setStyleSheet(
    "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad,x1:0,y1:1,x2:0,y2:0," \
    "    stop:0 rgba(34, 34, 44, 255)," \
    "    stop:1 rgba(56, 55, 72, 255)" \
    ");"
);
```

[image]